# FactoryGirl—Add a has_many record to a factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

With FactoryGirl I know I can make singular attributes like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    trading_name { FFaker::Company.name }
    legal_type { legal_types.keys.sample }
    updated_by { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    ...
```

Now I'm trying to add a user, but not sure how to do it.

I tried:

```
users { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

But got an error on an `each` loop because `users` wasn't the collection of users, it was changed to be that single user.

So how do you create `has_many` objects in a factory? How do you make sure they are linked to each other? Some people do an `after(:create)` but I'd like to make the users before saving the `Company` record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Association` section](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) of Factory Girl documentation says to use `after(:create)`. In your case code will be:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    ...

    after(:create) do |company|
      create_list(:user, 3, company: company)
    end
```

**Update**: In a case you have `after_save` validation in `User` model you may use `after(:build)` hook instead of `after(:create)`:

```
    after(:build) do |company|
      company.users << build(:user)
    end
```

Comment: My problem is that the `Company` model has an `after_save` callback that needs the `user` to exist. The model's callbacks trigger before the factory's callbacks.

Comment: I've added a description for this case to the answer, pls check it.

Comment: would you need to state `build(:user, company: company)`, or is that automatic since you are adding it to `company.users`?

Comment: Rails automatically will set `company_id` for the `user`.